# Issue while running Java code through terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, terminal

I am trying to make sample program to ran excel (xlsx) spreadsheet and load the data in 2 dimensional array.I have Googled and found some good samples.
But the problem i am facing is that it's not getting run through Terminal though it's working fine when i run the code from eclipse.

Here i am attaching screen shot of error i am getting while running code through terminal :-

[image]

The code i am using is :-

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExcelDemo xread2 = new ExcelDemo();
    }

    public ExcelDemo() {
        getvalue_1();
    }

    public static void getvalue_1() {
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        String[][] value = null;
        double[][] nums = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/home/ravi/Desktop/abc/Firebase/sid.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            // get sheet number
            int sheetCn = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            for (int cn = 0; cn < sheetCn; cn++) {
                // get 0th sheet data
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(cn);
                // get number of rows from sheet
                int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                // get number of cell from row
                int cells = sheet.getRow(cn).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                value = new String[rows][cells];
                for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                    row = sheet.getRow(r); // bring row
                    if (row != null) {
                        for (int c = 0; c < cells; c++) {
                            cell = row.getCell(c);
                            nums = new double[rows][cells];
                            if (cell != null) {
                                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                    value[r][c] = cell.getCellFormula();
                                    break;

                                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    value[r][c] = ""
                                            + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                    break;

                                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    value[r][c] = ""
                                            + cell.getStringCellValue();
                                    break;

                                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                    value[r][c] = "[BLANK]";
                                    break;

                                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                                    value[r][c] = "" + cell.getErrorCellValue();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                }
                                System.out.print(value[r][c]);

                            } else {
                                System.out.print("[null]\t");
                            }
                        } // for(c)
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
                } // for(r)
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Jars which i am using in this demo are as follows :-

1. dom4j.jar
2. poi-3.9.jar
3. poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar
4. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta1.jar
5. xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using libraries you need to put them on the classpath when compiling too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `javac` is for compilation, and if you try to use it you need to specify classpath. I assume it is not what you want, you want to run it and not compile it right? The simplest way to run it from command line:

Create "runnable jar" by using eclipse "Export runnable jar" tool (right mouse button on project->export->java->runnable jar file-> select the proper class that contains the main() to be run, **please select option "Copy the required jars in folder next to the destination jar"**. Then run it by entering the dest jar folder from console and invoking:

```
java -jar yourDestJarName.jar
```

Comment: Hey Krzysztof Cichocki, Thanks for your reply , yes i tried to add jar files by running the above mentioned command , it was working fine with one jar , but when i try to put all 5 jars , then this command do not load all files.

Comment: Please do the same, and pay attention to the step described in bold text.

Comment: okay , let me try this , will let you know the result ,thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you Man...I really appreciate your help